# How can I have textarea and graphics in the same jpanel?

Tags: java, graphics

I have two classes One for graphics and one for user input via text using textarea. When I run them in the same package only one of them runs how could I run both together so that the graphics will run with the user input.

Here is the graphics

```
package pack;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui extends JPanel implements Runnable{ 

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    input inputObject = new input();
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new gui();
    }

    public gui()
    {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        System.out.println("::");
        f.setTitle("Basic window");
            f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setFocusable(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        t.start(); System.out.println(":::");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                t.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            x++;
            y++;

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println(":D");

        g.setColor(Color.red);

        g.drawString("hi",x,y);
    }
}
```

Here is the text

```
package pack;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class input extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

 protected JTextField textField;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public input()
    {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textField.selectAll();


        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        frame.add(new input());


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add input to gui, in your gui constructor, create an instance of the other class and add it to to gui

```
// in gui()
input my_input = new input();
add(my_input);
```

tip: class names should start with capital letter.
tip2: you should only have main method in one class, and add other classes to it.

Let me know if you understood or you need more help.

Comment: I added that in to the gui constructor but it did not do anything also when I remove the main from the input class where do I put what is in the main in input class